# What do eigenvalues have to do with modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules, representation-theory, irreducible-representation

> Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order 4 , given by the presentation
> $$G = \left\langle a: a^4 = 1\right\rangle.$$
> Let $F$ be $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V$ be a 2-dimensional vector space over $F$ with basis $\mathcal{B} = \left\{v_1, v_2\right\}$. It turns out that $V$ can be made into a left $FG$-module in which the generator $a \in G$ acts as
> $$a \cdot v_1 = v_2 \quad \text { and } \quad a \cdot v_2 = -v_1.$$
> Let $\rho: FG \rightarrow GL_2(F)$ be the representation of $G$ corresponding to this module. Show that $V$ is an irreducible $FG$-module.

I am working on a homework problem to show that a certain FG-module is irreducible and my professor told us to "look at the eigenvectors." I wasn't sure why we should do that, but I went ahead and found that the two eigenvalues were $\lambda = \pm i$ with associated eigenvectors $<-i, 1>$ and $<i, 1>$. I was hoping to see the connection after finding them, but I can't see why finding these eigenvectors should show that an FG-module is irreducible.

My question is this: What do eigenvalues have to do with modules?

Comment: It is somewhat surprising that you think that you gave enough Information on your problem for us to help you. As it is often the case, a concrete question is easier to explain than a general one ("what do eigenvalues have to do with modules?" Is essentially unanswerable!) yet you gave literally no details about the concrete problem you have. Something seems to have two eigenvalues and some eigenvectors. First rule of the MSE club is make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Okay, I'll add more details.

Comment: If a 2-dimensional module is reducible, it must have a 1-dimensional submodule. That must be an eigenspace.

Comment: An eigenspace of what?

Comment: Ok, now with the details at hand. If the module were reducible, it would have a proper nonzero submodule. The only possible dimension of such a thing is 1: if you pick any nonzero element in it that vector will therefore be an eigenvectors for all the elements of the group. If you show, for example, that some element in the group does.not have any eigenvector, then you are thus done.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was trying to give enough of a hint but yes, as you say, a $1$-dimensional submodule for any module is a simultaneous eigenvector for all generators of the group (and therefore all elements).

Comment: Btw, what you called eigenvalues and  eigenvectors are not eigenvalues and eigenvectors, because the first do not belong to the field you are working with, and the latter do not belong to the module you are working with. Calling such things eigenthings is a sadly common bad practice one is usually exposed to in linear algebra.

Comment: Okay, I think understand. Because the eigenvalues are both complex, they couldn't possibly span $\mathbb{R}$, thus the FG-module is irreducible. Is this correct?

Comment: If anyone could write this up in an answer I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone could write this up in an answer I would really appreciate it.

Sure

As David wrote in the comments:

> If a 2-dimensional module is reducible, it must have a 1-dimensional submodule. That must be an eigenspace.

Now we are going to find the eigenspaces of our $\mathbb{R}G$-module $V$. You already did something like that:

> found that the two eigenvalues were $\lambda=\pm i$ with associated eigenvectors $(−i,1)$ and $(i,1)$.

However, these are not real eigenvectors, as Mariano said:

> What you called eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not eigenvalues and eigenvectors, because the first do not belong to the field you are working with, and the latter do not belong to the module you are working with

That is, our module action does not have eigenvectors when we restrict our numbers to $F=\mathbb{R}$; we have $(-i,1)\notin V$ and $\pm i\notin\mathbb{R}$.

Hence, we find that our action $\mathbb{R}G\to GL(V)$ does *not* have eigenvectors in $V$. Therefore, $V$ does not have a 1-dimensional submodule. Therefore, it is not reducible.